# Rails 3 soap server implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap

I am building an integration with my rails webapp and quickbook desktop application. Quickbook expect me to implement a soap webservice so that my application can talk to it.

I am relatively new to the rails framework. I can see that there is no built in support for  soap web service in rails 3.

After hours of googling I found two gems soap4r and wash_out. But I dont see a working soap server implementation using any of these two. 
People recommend savon, but I believe it's only for soap client implementation.

Can somebody guide me here on what I should I do? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've just updated wash_out to 0.2.0. It has brand new look and actually works *sigh*.

At the moment AFAIK it's the only gem allowing you to build SOAP Server over the Rails 3. Since 0.2.0 it requires Rails 3.1 though.

Take a look at docs on Github: https://github.com/roundlake/wash_out. It has several examples in README.

Comment: the repo is empty. have u migrated this?

Comment: Ehm. Yes. And it's written in the README of the previous repo. http://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out is the new location.

Comment: sry . I was sleeping I guess